# Rails Activerecord query through three associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Company has_many :agents, Agent belongs_to :company.

Agent has_many :comments, Comment belongs_to both :agent and :business.

Business has_many :comments.

What ActiveRecord query finds all the businesses with a comment written by an agent of the company?

I can get all the comments for all the agents of a company:

`@company.agents.joins(:comments)`

And using that query I can pluck all the business_ids that are commented on by company agents:

`@company.agents.joins(:comments).pluck(:business_id)`

(So if nothing else works I *could* get the desired list of businesses using a *second* query into Business given an array of IDs.)

However I cannot seem to extend the association chain in a single query to includes the Businesses, eg, a query that finds the Business record for each business commented upon by company agents, eg something like:

`@company.agents.joins(:comments).joins(:business)` # Can't join 'Agent' to association named 'businesses'

EDIT:

Tried `@company.agents.joins(:comments => :business)` as suggested by Jon in the comments. That works if doing a .count() or a .pluck().

If need to also query by Business fields, that can be done with:

```
@company.agents.joins(:comments => :business).where(:businesses => {:account_status => :active})
```

Comment: It looks like you're putting the second `join` onto the `agents` scope. Have you tried doing something like this: `@company.agents.joins(:comments => :business)`?

Comment: Bingo, yes, thank you. I thought I'd tried that, perhaps I got the plural/singular incorrect earlier.

Comment: although @company.agents.joins(:comments => :business) still does not permit then appending additional queries such as where("business.status = ?", 'active') whcih gives the error "missing FROM-clause entry for table "business""

Comment: .where(:businesses => {:account_status => :active}) is the key

Comment: Jon if want to re-post as an answer i'll happily accept it

Comment: Haha - I was just about to give you the `.where` query. I'll type it up for you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the second `join` query onto the `agents` scope. You'll need to use something like the following:

```
@company.agents.joins(:comments => :business)
```

If you need to add conditions against the business you can do so as follows:

```
@company.agents.joins(:comments => :business).where(:businesses => {:account_status => :active})
```

This way it correctly chains the join queries for you and adds the conditions to the appropriate tables.